# C# Asp.net core. Authorization between two services using 2 secret keys

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-5

I need to grant a remote service access to one of the API points. Therefore, I want to create a simple authorization between 2 services using 2 secret keys that I will store in configuration files. At first I wanted to use OpenID Dict, but I don't want to complicate the application and I also don't want to reinvent the wheel. Can anyone know examples of such implementations?(Specifically my example, I want to allow a console application (NET 5) access to a single point of the Web API (NET 5))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily achieve using api key. Remote service passes in authorization header apiKey which is validated by API endpoint.